# Dart: decode Json from a Firebase snapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart

it's probably a trivial question, I try to decode a json from a Firebase snapshot, here is the structure of the json :

```
firebaseKey1 : {img1:value1}

firebaseKey2 : {img2:value2}

firebaseKey3 : {img3:value3}
```

**Here is what I tried:**

```
 DatabaseReference firebaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
 firebaseRef.child('...').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic,dynamic> map = snapshot.value;
      map.forEach((key, jsonString) {
            print('$key: $jsonString'); // jsonString = {img1:value1}

            //how to get value1 inside jsonString?
     });
 });
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think you don't need to decode. It should return the value decoded already.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886373/flutter-wait-until-firebase-data-are-retrieved-and-a-string-modified-before-wri?noredirect=1#comment94619363_53886373  ? I'm really stuck.. :(

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `json.decode`. The returned value is already decoded.

```
{key1:value1}
```

is the result of

```
final Map<String,dynamic> value = {'key1': 'value1'};
print(value.toString());
```

Comment: Hey Günter. From the log output it seems like Julien might have a nested object. Would a `jsonString.forEach()` work in that case?

Comment: I thought so at first, but it's invalid JSON because it is missing quotes, but it matches the output of Darts `Map.toString()`.

Comment: I edited the question with the whole json structure, indeed how to get "value" inside the jsonString? it's needed another Map<String,dynamic>?

Comment: Still doesn't look like JSON. `{"img1":"value1"}` would be valid JSON

Comment: What is the questiin about anyway? Do you get an error message?

Comment: no error msg, I simply would like to get value1 for eg, which is inside jsonString

Comment: and here is how I save data (using a cloud fnt): .push().set({ [key] : url }),  maybe the problem comes from here.. to get a valid json, I add quotes around key and url? (I simply need to save a list of image name and url, and to retrieve them in the code in the question)

Comment: If it is actually JSON, then use `json.decode(jsonString)` or `jsonDecode(jsonString)` from `dart:convert` but you had that in your question already so I still don't understand where the problem lies.

Comment: see also https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-manually-using-dartconvert

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer In my experience the platform SDKs log the DataSnapshot in custom formats, instead of writing the original JSON. :-(

Comment: Interesting. I derived my conclusion from the comment after `print(...)` which should print the Dart value. Hard to tell exactly without seeing it in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what the OP is looking for is:

```
var parsedJSON  = snapshot.value;
print('img1 : ' + parsedJSON['img1']);
```