# Flutter - Dart : wait a forEach ends

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I try to modify a string using data in each node I retrieve from Firebase database, and then to write a file with the modifed string (called "content").

**Here is what I tried :**

```
// Retrieve initial content from Firebase storage
var data = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("...").getData(1048576);
var content = new String.fromCharCodes(data);

// Edit content with each node from Firebase database
final response = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('...').once();
response.value.forEach((jsonString) async {
     ...
     // cacheManager.getFile returns a Future<File>
     cacheManager.getFile(signedurl).then((file){ 
         // Modify content
         content=content.replaceAll('test',file.path);
     });
});

// Finally write the file with content
print("test");
final localfile = File('index.html');
await localfile.writeAsString(content);
```

**Result :**

"test" is shown before the forEach ends.

I found that we can do in Dart (https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/GHm2cKUxUDU) :

> await Future.forEach

but in my case if I do : await Future.response.value.forEach  (sounds a bit weird)

then I get :

> Getter not found: 'response'.
>       await Future.response.value.forEach((jsonString) async {

How to wait that forEach ends (with "content" modified) before to write the file with new content?

Any idea?

Comment: I do not know Dart, but I think you should use some `map` value instead of a `forEach` one, in order to return an array of `Promises` (or the like in Dart language, `Futures` maybe ?) to be able to "await" for all. Here you are just creating some asynchronous behavior but they are not blocking, thus making the `print("test")` code to be executed.

Answer (score 18):

If you use `for(... in )` instead of `forEach` you can use `async`/`await`

```
Future someMethod() async {
  ...

  for(final jsonString in response.value) {
     ...
     // cacheManager.getFile returns a Future<File>
     cacheManager.getFile(signedurl).then((file){ 
         // Modify content
         content=content.replaceAll('test',file.path);
     });
  });
}
```

With `forEach` the calls fire away for each `jsonString` immediately and inside it `await` works, but `forEach` has return type `void` and that can't be awaited, only a `Future` can.

Answer (score 8):

You defined the callback for forEach as `async`, which means that it runs asynchronously. In other words: the code inside of that callback runs independently of the code outside of the callback. That is exactly why `print("test");` runs before the code inside of the callback.

The simplest solution is to move all code that needs information from within the callback *into* the callback. But there might also be a way to [await all of the asynchronous callbacks](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#calling-multiple-funcs), similar to how you already `await` the `once` call above it.

**Update** I got working what I think you want to do. With this JSON:

```
{
  "data" : {
    "key1" : {
      "created" : "20181221T072221",
      "name" : "I am key1"
    },
    "key2" : {
      "created" : "20181221T072258",
      "name" : "I am key 2"
    },
    "key3" : {
      "created" : "20181221T072310",
      "name" : "I am key 3"
    }
  },
  "index" : {
    "key1" : true,
    "key3" : true
  }
}
```

I can read the index, and then join the data with:

```
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("/53886373");
final index = await ref.child("index").once();
List<Future<DataSnapshot>> futures = [];
index.value.entries.forEach((json) async {
  print(json);
  futures.add(ref.child("data").child(json.key).once());
});
Future.wait(futures).then((List<DataSnapshot> responses) {
  responses.forEach((snapshot) {
    print(snapshot.value["name"]);
  });
});
```

Comment: How can we achieve for firestore

Comment: The code for Firestore should be very similar, as it also returns `Future`s. If you're having a hard time making it work, open a new question with the minimal code that reproduces what *you* tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
File file = await cacheManager.getFile(signedurl);
content = content.replaceAll('test', file.path);
```

instead of:

```
cacheManager.getFile(signedurl).then((file){ ...});
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a fuller example trying to replicate what you have. I use a `for` loop instead of the `forEach()` method:

```
void main () async {
  List<String> str = await getFuture();
  print(str);
  var foo;

  for (var s in str) {
    var b = await Future(() => s);
    foo = b;
  }

  print('finish $foo');
}

getFuture() => Future(() => ['1', '2']);
```